# Is moving over to a Portable Class Library a breaking change?

Tags: .net, versioning, portable-class-library, semantic-versioning

At the moment I am building separate binaries to target each runtime

- .net 4
- Windows Phone
- Silverlight

Now if I move the library over to be a single [Portable Class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx), and I am not changing the functionality, is this considered a breaking change?

Or in [SemVer](http://semver.org/) terms is it a major, minor or patch version change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say this is a minor version change because code which links against your library is now subject to [some specific whims of the PCL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx):

> When you deploy a .NET Framework 4 application that references a Portable Class Library assembly, you must specify a dependency on the .NET Framework 4 update. By specifying this dependency, you ensure that the update is installed with your application.

Also, if you have exposed [certain Framework types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597392.aspx), consumers of the code may need to change.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. As sixlettervariables called out, if previously targeting 4.0, yes, it is a breaking change to move to portable because you now have a dependency on a .NET Framework Update that you previously didn't. With the other platforms (or if targeting .NET 4.0.3 or higher), no, it not a breaking change.

Answer (score 1):

While in theory this should be a minor change in reality it is a little more complicated.

Speaking form experience I have had several issues with upgrading assemblies to Portable class Libraries. These include:

- IIS with .net 4 would not load an PCL assembly because it could not find "System.Core".
- Mono 2.10 has issues with Portable Class Libraries. Rumoured to be fixed in Mono 2.12 http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.12

These are most likely teething issues that will be solved in the future. But just be mindful of the possible upstream issues you may cause consumers of your library.

Comment: The IIS issue is probably due to the lack of the 4.0 update called out in the docs as in my comment. Mono is a good point, and I didn't factor that in.

Answer (score 0):

I would say if you can simply drop the new assembly in and everything just continues to work like it did before without any code modifications, then it's not a breaking change.

Switching to a PCL is a fairly neutral operation from the library consumer's perspective. It's still just a class library to them.

In semver terms, I think it would count as a minor version.